# Is there _JAVA_OPTIONS on Mac?

Tags: java, windows, macos

I was wondering if there was _JAVA_OPTIONS on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS). If yes, how can I get to it like on Windows (windows key and pause/break)?

Answer (score 0):

_JAVA_OPTIONS, is an environment variable, theres is no screen on mac for setting it like on windows, you have to define it on your terminal (for that session) or in a file (for all future sessions) if you choose to set it on a file, that could be .bash_profile o .zshrc depending on which terminal you use, take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@himanshuagarwal1395/setting-up-environment-variables-in-macos-sierra-f5978369b255)for an example